# get scraped data/variable from node.js for utilisation in javascript application

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, parsing

i am creating a language web application. It will randomly show a word in English and ask the participant for the latin equivalent. I've managed to work out how to scrape definitions etc from a language website. and can print the text on the "command prompt" but i am having difficulty getting the information to show in javascript or html. I am new to node.js and javascript. I need help with the coding that turns my node.js variables into variables i can use in my javascript/html coding....(thanks in advance)
ps pls avoid "client side" "server side" jargon as i am new to computer programming.

Comment: You'll want to look into XHR requests - this is the standard way to communicate with your server (node.js is your server). Check out http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Comment: thanks looking into it as we speak